# Arabic custom font in Android webView

Tags: android, webview, fonts

I am trying to add Arabic custom fontto webView with no luck. In my case, webView renders the default font shipped with the device.

I have tried ttf and otf font types also converted font type to svg through [https://everythingfonts.com](http://everythingfonts) with no luck

here is my code:

html file stored in the assets folder:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;" charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        /** Specify a font named "MyFont",
        and specify the URL where it can be found: */
        @font-face {
        font-family: "MyFont";
        src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/NotoKufiArabic-Bold.ttf') format(‘truetype’); ;
        }
        h3 { font-family:"MyFont"}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>
مرحبا</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

MainActivity where i call webView:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting reference to WebView of the activity_main layout
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        // Loading an html page into webview
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html");
    }
 ...........
 ...........
```

my code is working fine in case of English text and font but nothing for Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<h3 dir="rtl" lang="ar"> arabic text </h3>` :

- `dir="rtl"` inform that the text is arabix
- `lang="ar"` renders form right to left